# How would I write a loop in R that is checking for changes in a json file and append it to a list?

Tags: json, r, stream

I have a .json file that is being updated every few minutes. How would I write a loop in R that is checking for changes into the file? I was thinking of using the fileSnapshot and changedFiles function. I want to append the character string from the json file into a list until the .json file stops updating. This is my current incomplete code:

```
msg <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("order.json"), collapse=""))
msgList <- list()

some sort of loop:{
    count <- length(msgList)+1
    msgList[[count]]<- msg
}
```

Comment: You are asking a bunch of different questions here. Can you focus in on one thing that is stopping you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some general ideas.  I use `md5sum` from the `tools` package to check if the file has been updated.  The `if` block within `while(...) {}` simulates probabilistic updating of the file.  One question is how you know the file has *finally* stopped updating.  Here I use `j` as a counter that breaks the loop only if the file has not been updated after 3 loops.

```
library(tools)

writeLines(text=paste(Sys.time()), "foo.txt")
new <- old <- md5sum("foo.txt")
msg <- list()
msg[[1]] <- readLines("foo.txt")
i <- 2
j <- 1
while(!identical(old, new) | j<3) {
  if (!identical(old, new)) {
    msg[[i]] <- readLines("foo.txt")
    j <- 1
    i <- i + 1
  } else {
    j <- j + 1
  }
  old <- new  
  Sys.sleep(1)  
  if(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1, p=c(.6, .4))) {
    cat("Updating\n")
    writeLines(text=paste(Sys.time()), "foo.txt")
  }
  new <- md5sum("foo.txt")
}

unlist(msg)
#  [1] "2016-08-11 17:50:49" "2016-08-11 17:50:51" "2016-08-11 17:50:53"
#  [4] "2016-08-11 17:50:54" "2016-08-11 17:50:55" "2016-08-11 17:50:57"
#  [7] "2016-08-11 17:50:58" "2016-08-11 17:50:59" "2016-08-11 17:51:00"
# [10] "2016-08-11 17:51:01" "2016-08-11 17:51:04" "2016-08-11 17:51:07"
# [13] "2016-08-11 17:51:09" "2016-08-11 17:51:10"
```